# Language of login.salesforce.com

Tags: login, language

**Situation**

For years I'm using salesforce. I had to login thousands of time through login.salesforce.com. I noticed that the language of the login language changes (probably dependent on the computer or browser I was using.

**Question**

Does anyone know how is the language of the standard Salesforce login page set?
(e.g. cookies?)

Can we influence/force it to a specific language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen before - thanks to CyberJus for your answer - it is possible to change the language based on the browser language.

However, it is possible to overrule this setting by using the url parameter locate. Locate overrules the browser settings and displays the website in any given language:

- https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=de
- https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=fr
- https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=uk
- https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=us

Answer (score 5):

It uses your default browser settings to set the language

Here I have set my language to german

[image: Here I have set my language to german]

And the resulting login page

[image: Login page]

Once you are logged in, it will use your locale settings in your profile.

Comment: your answer I believe is incomplete - in my case, my browser (Chrome) language is "English" however my login page in my broswer is in French, last week it was in Spanish

Comment: There is also a cookie "com.salesforce.LocaleInfo" that, if set, takes priority over the browser language.

Comment: I have users that have Spanish as their browser language and still get a German login page. I am pretty sure they never got a cookie with German as the locale.

Comment: Per my experience, the language is also set from the default language of the latest org/user you connected to.
So if working for multiple customer, you can end up with any language on the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in the Locale Settings on the Company Information page