# 'Refresh Sandbox' changes to different languages randomly. What causes this?

Tags: sandbox

I have noticed that in Setup | Sandboxes, the 'Refresh Sandbox' text randomly changes to different languages from time to time. For example, as per the screenshots, one of the sandboxes had information in Italian and another in French.

I checked my user locale and confirmed that it is English and I also checked across all my browsers that my default language is English, so I am confused why this has happened.

I cannot replicate this issue anymore though since the sandbox information for all sandboxes is all in English now, but I dare say the language could change again. This isn't an big issue for me but rather, i'm confused why and how this is happening.

I noticed that other Salesforce users have raised similar questions [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73991/language-of-login-salesforce-com) and [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000i0qHAAQ) but I haven't come across an answer to explain this.

[image]

[image]